# Как правильно создавать сервер, чтобы его можно было перезагружать?

Tags: node.js, сервер

У меня несколько вопросов в одном. Что происходит с сервером, когда он работает с nodemon и я его перезагружаю? И от сюда второй вопрос - нужно ли при перезагрузке переподключаться к db? И нужно ли как-то правильно разделять файлы инициализации сервера, чтобы эта перезагрузка происходила наиболее безболезненно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nodemon стартует node-приложение в отдельном процессе и завершает его, когда это требуется. Поэтому с вашим приложением в nodemon происходит всё тоже самое, что если бы вы его запустили/остановили сами. Для вашего приложения должно быть без разницы первый это запуск или десятый.